# How do I prove $e^{x+2y}$ is differentiable at $(2,2)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Practice Problem: Prove $e^{x+2y}$ is differentiable at $(2,2)$.

The practice problem requires me to use this definition of differentiability:

$f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y) = Ah+Hk + g(h,k)\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$

where

$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}g(h,k) \to 0$

I started by simplifying the LHS with the given values and got:

$f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y) = e^{6+h+2k}-e^6 = e^6 (e^{h+2k}-1) = \frac{e^6 (e^{h+2k}-1)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$

This satisifies the first part of the definition, but I struggle with proving that the limit approaches zero:

$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{e^6 (e^{h+2k}-1)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$

I don't know how to approach this. I've plugged it into some solvers on the web but didn't get good answers. Did I make a mistake earlier or have I just forgot how to solve this kind of limit?

Edit: I'm aware that there are other, simpler ways to do this. The goal is to do a couple of these directly from the definition before diving into that so I can improve my understanding.

Comment: Your particular limit DNE as can be checked with paths $h=0$ and $k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to compute the supposed-to-be differential in order to find $A$ and $B$, and check they fulfill the definition. Your calculations are incomplete so far.

For a different approach, since $f$ is continuous it suffices that the partial derivatives are continuous to have a differentiable map.